# Devise generators use erb instead of haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml

I'm trying to generate haml views with devise, but it always use erb instead. I'm running rails 3.1 & ruby 1.9.2. Rails generators (like scaffold) generates haml. I tried setting the template engine :

```
 config.generators do |g|
    g.template_engine :haml
  end
```

But still doesn't work. If you have an idea, it is most welcomed.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate Views for Devise in HAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676663/how-to-generate-views-for-devise-in-haml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to generate them out of the box. However, there is a short [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views) on how to convert the erb views from devise to haml layout using `html2haml` and a simple bash script.

Answer (score 1):

That means that Devise doesn't have templates for HAML. However like @halfdan said it's pretty easy to convert with html2haml...