# How to Generate Views for Devise in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml

This is mine Gemfile

```
gem 'haml'
group :development do
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
end
```

I then executed the following statements in a terminal/command window:

```
bundle install
rails generate devise:views users -e haml
```

or

```
rails generate devise:views users -t = haml
```

But creating devise views in erb. how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have to do this

```
rails generate devise:views

gem "html2haml"
bundle install

for file in app/views/devise/**/*.erb; do html2haml -e $file ${file%erb}haml && rm $file; done
```

and now it is perfect.

Also see the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views)

Comment: its simply erb to haml conversion case. you may use any sort of haml converter.

Answer (score 37):

Even simpler solution.

I have erb2haml installed in the development section of my Gemfile, so I just run:

```
rails generate devise:views
rake haml:erb2haml
# or
rake haml:replace_erbs # outdated
```

Done!

Comment: Easy! Until `html2haml` gem updates its dependency on `ruby_parser`, it may be necessary to reference the repository directly so that the rake task will work in Ruby 2.1.1. `gem 'haml-rails' gem 'html2haml', github: 'haml/html2haml' gem 'ruby_parser', github: 'seattlerb/ruby_parser'`

Comment: @scarver2 - No longer necessary

Answer (score 2):

Have a quick look here. It gives in details explanation itself from devise documentation

[How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views)

Answer (score 0):

seems that the option to indicate which template engine to use is missing (version 3.0.0). An issue has been open for this. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2455

Answer (score 0):

its simply erb to haml conversion case. you may use any sort of haml converter. Like this one
http://htmltohaml.com/